# chosen state of li item

Tags: css

I have a question regarding a menu. If I select an `li` item, I want that selected item to have the same background-color property as the `li:hover` state and stay so, until I hover and choose another `li` item.

This is my html:

```
<div class="submenu-container">
    <div class="submenunavYH">
        <p>YH Högskola</p>
        <div class="submenusettings"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="submenuYH submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="utbild.html">
                <p>Visual Merchandiser YH</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="lia.html">
                <p>LIA</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">
                <p>FAQ</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="ansok.html">
                <p>Ans&ouml;k h&auml;r</p>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.submenu-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #f3f0ef;
    margin: 3% auto 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.submenunavYH, .submenunavRetail, .submenunavProjekt{
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.submenunavYH{
    background-color: #660066;
}

.submenunavRetail{
    background-color: #336600;
}


.submenunavProjekt{
    background-color: #000000;
}  

.submenuYH ul li:hover {
    border-left:3px solid #cc66cc;
    background-color:rgba(204,102,204,0.1);
}

.submenuRetail ul li:hover {
    border-left:3px solid #99CC66;
    background-color:rgba(153, 204, 102,0.1);
}

.submenuProjekt ul li:hover {
    border-left:3px solid #666666;
    background-color:rgba(102, 102, 102,0.1);
}

.submenusettings {
    height:20px;
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    margin:10px;
}

.submenu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.submenu ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 11px 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
    text-indent: 10px;

}

.submenu ul li a {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#a4a3a3;
    font-family: 'Strait', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

If I for example for a:active have the same attributes as the `.submenuYH ul li:hover` will it maintain those attributes even after I release the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

code your menu as an unordered list with ids and classes as needed for style and position:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="parentLi"><a><span>YH Högskola</span></a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li id="childLi"><a href="#">Visual Merchandiser YH</a></li>
                <li id="siblingLi1"><a href="#">LIA</a></li>
                <li id="siblingLi2"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You can use javascript and add classes as needed for highlighting path to selected page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#parentLi').addClass('current');
     $('#childLi').addClass('selected');
)};
```

then just create the classes `.current` and `.selected` to have the same style as your hover.
You will need to have css selectors styled such as these:

```
   #menu {
   }
   #menu > ul span {
   }
   #menu li ul li {
   }
   #menu li {
   }
   #menu li ul li:hover {
   }
   #menu li ul {
   }
   #menu li ul li {
   }
   #menu li ul li a {
   }
```

You can see the full effect [on this site](http://energypros.com/EnergyEfficiency-Insulation-Attic-Insulation.html). as you hover energy efficiency you will see that all of the parents are highlighted as well as the current page